# Unity: Trying to get my bullet to shoot horizontally on the X-axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get my bullets sprite to shoot horizontally. I used this code to try but it ended up shooting vertically instead. Any advice on what I should change? I tried using 2 codes, one with ScreenToWorldPoint and the other in ViewportToWorldPoint. My bullet disappeared immediately when I used ScreenToWorldPoint while the bullets travelled horizontally when using ViewportToWorldPoint

Code 1(ViewportToWorldPoint)

```
    void Update()
    {
        //get the bullet's current position
        Vector2 position = transform.position;

        //compute the bullet's new position by getting the x and y position, plus speed * time
        position = new Vector2(position.x, position.y + speed * Time.deltaTime);

        //update the bullet's position 
        transform.position = position;

        //setting the maximum points of the screen
        Vector2 max = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(1, 1));

        //if the bullet went out of the screen coordinates set at the top, destroy the bullet
        if (transform.position.x > max.x)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Code 2(ScreenToWorldPoint)

```
    void Update()
    {
        //get the bullet's current position
        Vector2 position = transform.position;

        //compute the bullet's new position by getting the x and y position, plus speed * time
        position = new Vector2(position.x, position.y + speed * Time.deltaTime);

        //update the bullet's position 
        transform.position = position;

        //setting the maximum points of the screen
        screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));

        //if the bullet went out of the screen coordinates set at the top, destroy the bullet
        if (transform.position.x > screenBounds.x * -2)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding to the y-position, not the x.

```
position = new Vector2(position.x, position.y + speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Should probably be:

```
position = new Vector2(position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime, position.y);
```

Comment: you're welcome!  would you mind accepting the answer as correct?  My account's new and I'm trying to earn privileges :D